# Pine Script - Send different alerts via indicator

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency, alerts

can someone help me with the option to send different alerts via one indicator ? Till now, I'm using `alertcondition()` in my pine script codes but when I saw Daviddtech strategy scripts I've seen he can send different alerts via one script.

Thank you all for your help !!

Comment: What do you mean by different alerts? You can have multiple `alertcondition()` calls in your script.

Comment: More powerful is the `alert` function. It allows you generate different alerts from one script with different messages.

Comment: I mean the alert function. I already use the alertcondition() but I want to generate different alerts from one script with different messages. For example, JSON messages to connect to 3commas bots

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.